# Create an SQL script with a Batch file and add multiple variables from a CSV file to that SQL script

Tags: mysql, batch-file, variables

I'm new with batch scripting and I'm struggling writing something that can:

1) Read an csv first columns and setting those values as variables.

2) Write a short sql sentence script adding all those variables to a WHERE 
   clause.

thats all...

What i've already done:

CSV File (variables to add)
[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx9c0.png)

Batch Code
[Batch Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA7wc.png)

Outcome Script :
[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAYCf.png)

What I need:
[MySQL Script Outcome from the batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIIhu.png)

any ideas to share?

Comment: Please cut and paste your code etc into the question, links are not a good idea here (because they may go away one day, and questions/answers here are supposed to be permanent), and no-one can search or copy/paste from images so they aren't a good idea either. If we could copy/paste your batch code, in particular, we'd be able to suggest approaches, perhaps. Having said which, as a long term user of tricks like this, I have these days been converted to using PHP and realised how much time I had wasted coding round the limitations of batch scripting.

Comment: No problem to add the code but as an image is more clear and the site allow it.... ill keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: The site allows images because of the need to post screenshots, I think.

Comment: good to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "_InputFile=%userprofile%\Desktop\FC3.txt"

set "seq="
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%A in (%_InputFile%) do (
    call set "seq=%%seq%%%%~A,"
)

set "seq=(%seq:~,-1%)"

> FinalStage.sql echo SELECT * FROM Totalfm3 WHERE Totalfm3.BRN IN %seq%

exit /b
```

`%userprofile%` is expected to be `C:Users\Martin` with your account.

`%seq%` stores the numbers separated by commas.

The `call set` does an additional parsing so `%%seq%%` evaluates the
value of the variable name of `seq` without needing delayed expansion.

`set "seq=(%seq:~,-1%)"` trims the last comma and adds parentheses around the
comma delimited values.

Finally, the SQL statement is written to file.

The tokens set in your `for` loop does not match the csv file sample.
I set tokens to `1` to match the csv file sample. You may need to
adjust the tokens to suit your needs.

---

To make multiline statement.

Change:

```
> FinalStage.sql echo SELECT * FROM Totalfm3 WHERE Totalfm3.BRN IN %seq%
```

to

```
(
    echo SELECT * FROM Totalfm3
    echo WHERE Totalfm3.BRN IN %seq%;
) > FinalStage.sql
```

Added `;` at end of statement as that is how MySQL ends a statement.

Comment: You are the batch scripting god!! this is awesome!! thanks... one last question, if I have a script longer than one row how should I break down that script  and insert the variable?

I was thinking in something like this:
(
  echo SELECT *
  echo FROM Totalfm3
  echo WHERE Totalfm3.BRN IN %seq% 
) > FinalStage.sql

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Extended answer with what I understand of your last question.